# If cell contains '?' then formula X if not then copy value

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, find, google-sheets-formula

At the moment I am busy with a spreadsheet to analyse results per url. The problem is that when I want to make a list of unique urls the urls with a parameter behind it (for example '?fbads') will be seen as unique, instead of that I need these results to be blended together with the main url. See example below:

https://www.holidayguru.nl/deal/accommodatie/luxe-strandvakantie-in-ijmuiden-5e25ba62-e001-4072-8eb5-b6c3b0e7e66f/?fbclid=IwA
&
https://www.holidayguru.nl/deal/accommodatie/luxe-strandvakantie-in-ijmuiden-5e25ba62-e001-4072-8eb5-b6c3b0e7e66f/

Should both be: https://www.holidayguru.nl/deal/accommodatie/luxe-strandvakantie-in-ijmuiden-5e25ba62-e001-4072-8eb5-b6c3b0e7e66f/

I already fixed this with a formula but I need one list with all urls. So I'm look for two options. Or in the

> =LEFT(A11,FIND("?",A11)-1)

That I use right now I need to find a way how I can say. *If you don't find a '?' than just copy cell A11*

Or...

I have to work with an if fuction to say, if A11 contains '?' than execute =left fuction otherwise use A11.

I can't manage to get the formula working. Demo sheet is down below :). Thanks!

[**Example spreadsheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EcOHM-7oQGd_afm-L1dxE_X_HfNRGlbtMCT9uulMLto/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete everything from Sheet1!A:A (including the header) and place the following in Sheet1!A1:

`=ArrayFormula({"UNIQUE URLS"; UNIQUE(FILTER(REGEXEXTRACT(URLs!A2:A,"[^\?]+"),URLs!A2:A<>""))})`

This will create the header (which you can change as you like within the formula itself) and a unique list of URLs as determined only by the portion before a question mark (if a question mark exists) or to the end of the original URL.

For your reference, the expression `[^\?]+` means "a string of the greatest length that can be extracted without containing a literal question mark."

`[ ]` = "any of the characters contained herein"

`[^ ]` = "not any of these characters"

`\` = literal marker (i.e., whatever is next will be treated as a literal character)

`\?` = literal question mark (using the literal marker before the `?` is necessary, since alone, the `?` has a separate special meaning in REGEX-type expressions)

`+` = "one or more of the preceding character or group of characters"

Comment: You're very welcome, Sami. I have added to my reply a brief tutorial on the REGEX components used in this solution.